# Shelve Pending Changes in Team Foundation server

Tags: tfs, codeplex

I am new to Team Foundation Server, so i was wondering what does "Shelve Pending Changes" does in Team foundation server. I am using TFS of project on Codeplex.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Shelve Pending Changes stores your code changes on the server but doesn't commit them to the branch. Here are some reasons I've used it:

1. To save changes but undo locally when I'm not ready to commit changes but I need to make an emergency bug fix on the same branch.
2. To store code for code reviews prior to committing. Other people can check out or view your shelved changes.
3. To store changes that are ready for committing when the changes aren't approved yet.

One thing to know about shelving changes: When you unshelve, you get the file as-is. If someone else has modified the file after your shelve, no merge happens. So I don't recommend shelving changes long-term.

Comment: just to be clear, you can **keep** changes locally (in your dev environment) when you shelve (which is useful for code reviews), or **discard** local changes (useful when you need to load another version / branch of the code to fix a bug)